# Rad Studio XE4 vs Delphi XE4

Tags: delphi, c++builder, delphi-xe4

My Delphi experience is as follows:

TP3 --> TP5.5 --> Delphi 3 --> Delphi 5 --> Delphi 2010

I have only purchased the Delphi product and have not even considered Rad Studio. I do not understand the difference between Rad Studio XE4 and Delphi XE4. I've looked at the feature matrix of both products and I'm still having a difficult time trying to understand the difference between the two products.

It's obvious that Rad Studio XE4 supports both Delphi and C++ (I get that). Besides C++ are there any differences between the Delphi Personality of Rad Studio XE4 and Delphi XE4?

Another way to ask this would be:

*"What can be done with Rad Studio XE4 that cannot be done with Delphi XE4?"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delphi in RAD Studio is Delphi. The difference is that in RAD Studio you also get `C++ Builder` and `HTML5 Builder`, as well as Mobile Studio (iOS development). If you also get Software Assurance you also get free upgrades during the support period (including new versions) for all of those products.

Answer (score 1):

RAD Studio is a bundle which mainly offers:

- Delphi
- C++Builder
- HTML5 Builder

For a same edition, the Delphi included with RAD Studio is the same.

Then, it depends more on the edition you choose... which changes the pack/addons you can get with it.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the two already correct answers: RAD Studio always consisted of Delphi and C++Builder, but the additional offerings varied over the years. Up to RAD Studio XE3 it also contained "Delphi Prism", which was a relabeled [Oxygene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygene_%28programming_language%29). We don't know if and how this will change again with future versions, but judging on the past, it probably will.